# Need help in understanding shape error while Building a CNN with sklearn and keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, scikit-learn, deep-learning

I try to load my dataset and design a CNN but when I try to train my model this error came up and I want to know how can I fix this?

```
ValueError: The channel dimension of the inputs should be defined. Found None.
```

and this is the way I split data

```
xtrain, xtest, ytrain, ytest = trian_test_split(images_total, 
                                                image_labels,
                                                stratify=image_labels,
                                                random_state=1234,
                                                test_size=0.2)

xvalid, xtest, yvalid, ytest= trian_test_split(xtest, 
                                                ytest,
                                                stratify=ytest,
                                                random_state=1234,
                                                test_size=0.5)


def read_img(path, label):
  file = tf.io.read_file(path)
  img = tf.image.decode_png(file)
  img = tf.image.resize(img, (32, 32))
  return img, label

train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((xtrain, ytrain))
train_dataset = train_dataset.map(read_img).batch(batch_size)

valid_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((xvalid, yvalid))
valid_dataset = valid_dataset.map(read_img).batch(batch_size)

test_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((xtest, ytest))
test_dataset = test_dataset.map(read_img).batch(batch_size)
```

And this is my model

```
num_classes = 26

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.Resizing(32, 32),
  tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.Rescaling(1./255),
  tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  layers.Dropout(0.2),
  tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_classes)
])
model.compile(
  optimizer='adam',
  loss=tf.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
  metrics=['accuracy'])


model.fit(train_dataset, epochs=5, validation_data=valid_dataset)
```

when I try to fit this model the error came up and I can't fix this

Comment: did you pass y label as well while calling model.fit ?

Comment: @Nagakiran No how should I do that? sorry I'm pretty new to this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't passed y label to model while calling, model needs both and x and y label to train accordingly,
[Here i added an example](https://towardsdatascience.com/building-a-convolutional-neural-network-cnn-in-keras-329fbbadc5f5)

please take a pause and go through videos of keras architecture and documentation in [keras io](https://keras.io/) these would give more information about deep learning modelling

once after you got familiar with all, jump to modelling

```
model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), epochs=3)
```

Comment: thank you for your help, I go through those videos after solving this problem because this is very important for me, I use this method and have an error that says 'ValueError: 'images' must have either 3 or 4 dimensions.' and when I can't reshape it with 'xtrain.reshape'  because xtrain is a list @Nagakiran

Comment: haa, your model actually, expecting in 3 dimensions, can you share xtrain, and ytrain shapes @khashayarehteshami

Comment: both xtrain and ytrain shapes are '(16640,)', both of them are lists

Comment: thats unapproved behaviour, you need to track the training data generation, seems you need to stack in new axis, please trace back to get 3 dimensionals, as those are images, they should follow 3d shape :-| @khashayarehteshami

Comment: thank you, I will find out what happens and why it came up as a list